# Blank Image on bucket.upload

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I am attempting to upload an image to my firebase storage with nodejs. I've used the following code:

```
 const bucketName = 'mybucket.appspot.com';

// The path to your file to upload
 const filePath = 'C:/Users/username/OneDrive/Desktop/testfunctions/dogs.png';

// The new ID for your GCS file
 const destFileName = 'your-new-file-name.png';


//function upload() {
     
    
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();

async function uploadFile() {
  await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filePath, {
    destination: destFileName,
  });

   console.log(`${filePath} uploaded to ${bucketName}`);
 }

uploadFile().catch(console.error);
```

However, upon uploading to my storage, the image fails to load, it is an infinite spinning bar, or there is none but just the file name.
Any help is appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghjV9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjhNh.png)

Comment: Instead of `async function uploadFile() {`, try `const uploadFile = async() => {`

Answer (score 1):

I Have Made This Code A While Ago When Searching I Saw That Nobody Solved Your Problem.

**This Method** Will **Save It In The "Storage"**. In Addition, Created A Link For It In **"Firebase Realtime Database"**

```
//Important Imports
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
const { uuid } = require("uuidv4");
const fs = require("fs");

//This Is Important Line To Tell The Firebase URL + STORAGE URL + CONNECT IT TO SERVICE ACCOUNT ADMIN
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL:
    "https://yourfirebase.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
  storageBucket: "gs://yourfirebasestorage.com",
});

// Get A Database Reference
const db = admin.database();
const ref = db.ref("Parent");
const usersRef = ref.child("Child");

uploadImageToFirebase("imageName", ".png");

//Upload Image To Firebase Function
function uploadImageToFirebase(imageName, imageFormat) {
  var myBucketLink = "yourfirebasestoragewithoutgs.appspot.com";
  // CHANGE: TO WERE YOU WANT THE ROOT TO BE
  //const usersRef = ref.child("anotherPath");

  var bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

  var filename = "./" + imageName + imageFormat;
  try {
    if (fs.existsSync(filename)) {
      var UUID = uuid();

      async function uploadFile() {
        const metadata = {
          metadata: {
            // This Line Is Very Important. It's To Create A Download Token.
            firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: UUID,
          },
          contentType: "image/png",
          cacheControl: "public, max-age=31536000",
        };
        // Uploads A Local File To The Bucket
        await bucket.upload(filename, {
          // Support For HTTP Requests Made With `Accept-Encoding: gzip`
          gzip: true,
          metadata: metadata,
        });

        console.log(`${filename} uploaded.`);
        var HTTP_ImageLink =
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/" +
          myBucketLink +
          "/o/" +
          imageName +
          imageFormat +
          "?alt=media&token=" +
          UUID;
        console.log(HTTP_ImageLink);
        usersRef.child("images").set({
          link: HTTP_ImageLink,
        });
      }

      uploadFile().catch(console.error);

    } else {
      console.log("Can't Upload");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: would the reference to the database be the same for cloud firestore?